Databricks Pyspark parse connection string
Is there an easy way to parse a connection string in this format?
HOST=HostName;Port=1234;ServiceName=Database;USer ID=User1;Password=Password123;

I need to parse out the host and port, database, user and password and assign them to separate variables.

Why not use python split with the ';' separator ? https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

what does it have to with pyspark or databricks? XD

Use str_to_map function to parse connection string as a map, then access each required item.
spark.sql("""
    SELECT str_to_map(conn, ';', '=') d,
           d['HOST'] as host,
           [... other values ...]
      FROM VALUES ('HOST=HostName;Port=1234;ServiceName=Database;USer ID=User1;Password=Password123;')
               AS d(conn)
""").show(1, False)
+---------------------------------------+--------+
|d                                      |host    |
+---------------------------------------+--------+
|{HOST -> HostName, Port -> 1234, [...]}|HostName|
+---------------------------------------+--------+


Assuming the order of the parameters doesn't change, you can do it in one line:
host_name, port_number, database_name, user_id, user_password = [item.split("=")[1] for item in connection_string.split(";") if item]

